# What is the probability of a system falling into an eigenstate after 3 measuremetns

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Given an operator $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{D}$, where $\hat{C}$ has eigenvectors $|\phi_1>$ and $|\phi_2>$, and $\hat{D}$ has $|\psi_1>$ and $|\psi_2>$. and they are related in the following fashion

$|\phi_1> = \frac{1}{5} (3|\psi_1> + 4|\psi_2>)$

$|\phi_2> = \frac{1}{5} (4|\psi_1> - 3|\psi_2>)$

A measurement of quantity $c$ is made and the system is in $|\phi_1>$. Then another measurement of quantity $d$, and following that a quantity $c$. What is the probability that the system will be found in state $|\phi_1>$ ? (Note c and d are associated with their respective operators $\hat{C}$ and $\hat{D}$)

I am thinking that by taking the $d$ quanitity measurement, it kind of resets the system. So that all of the four states have a probability associated with them. If we took two consecutive measurements of $c$ then we would have 100%  chance of being in $|\phi_1>$. but since we did not, there is 50% chance. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Edit: I say the above because $(4|\psi_1> - 3|\psi_2>)$ and $(3|\psi_1> + 4|\psi_2>)$ breakup similarly so, I assumed that it meant that they have the same likelyhoods

Comment: Your idea is right. But I don't think the probabilities will come to 50% exactly. You will have to calculate the probabilities explicitly.

Comment: Do I essentially just need to normailize? so force $\frac{3}{5}+\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{5}+\frac{4}{5}$ to be equal to 1, and then split it?Actually this is probably wrong because that would force the probability to be 50%

Comment: Remember two things 1) probabilities are square of absolute  value amplitudes. 2) The probability of one event happening after another event is the product of their individual probabilities.

Comment: hmmm ok, so I squared and then normalized. and then there are 3 measurements, so 50% for the first one $c$, then $d$ 50% of being in the state we want, and same with $c$. So 12.5%?, or would it be 25% since we know that the first c was in the state we want

Comment: i got 50 percent because i got $\psi_1 = 16/50$ and $\psi_2 = 9/50$ and the opposite for the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: $$ |\phi_1> = \frac{1}{5} (3|\psi_1> + 4|\psi_2>)$$ 
$$ |\phi_2> = \frac{1}{5} (4|\psi_1> - 3|\psi_2>)$$

Your system in question starts at $|\phi_1\rangle$. Next we measure $d$. So there it can collapse to $|\psi_1\rangle$ with probability $(\frac35)^2$ or $|\psi_2\rangle$ with probability $(\frac45)^2$.

Next we measure $c$. Possible out comes are $|\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_2\rangle$. To find the probabilities we have to write $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ in terms of $|\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_2\rangle$. Doing a bit of linear algebra,

$$ |\psi_1> = \frac{1}{5} (3|\phi_1> + 4|\phi_2>)$$ 
$$ |\psi_2> = \frac{1}{5} (4|\phi_1> - 3|\phi_2>)$$.

There are now two possibilities by which you could measure $|\phi_1\rangle$. First, the intial measurement gave $|\psi_1\rangle$ and then you got $|\phi_1\rangle$ now. Second,  First, the intial measurement gave $|\psi_2\rangle$ and then you got $|\phi_1\rangle$ now. The total probability of measuring $|\phi_1\rangle$ is then the sum of probabilities of these two possibilities. Which gives

$$ P(\phi_1) =  (\frac35)^2(\frac35)^2 +(\frac45)^2(\frac45)^2 = \frac{337}{625}$$.

Similarly try to find the probability of the other outcome ($\phi_2$). And check if they sum to one.

Comment: where can i go to look up that linear algebra step?  Thank you ! I really appreciate the help

Comment: It is just solving two linear equations. $\psi$'s are the unknowns  ($x$ and $y$). $\phi$'s are the constants.